# How to fix this Grails error?

Tags: grails, grails-2.2

I'm tried to install spring security core plugin and I have this error:

```
Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):
- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.0.RC1
- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.0.RC1
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: what version of spring-security are you trying to install?

Comment: Be sure to try a `grails clean` and `grails refresh-dependencies`.

Comment: I've done clean and refresh-dependencies

Comment: put this code into repositories block. `mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'`

Comment: Spring security is instaled, but now I have this error: Error 2014-05-15 14:48:33,891 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR [/dipl].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/dipl] threw exception.

Comment: and it says that build path is incomplete

Comment: what version of grails are you using/

Comment: I'm using Grails 2.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the custom snapshot/rc repository to the BuildConfigs repositories block

```
repositories {
  mavenRepo "http://repo.spring.io/milestone/"
}
```

Comment: That adds spring securit but I stil have an error :  Error 2014-05-15 14:48:33,891 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR [/dipl].[default] - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/dipl] threw exception. 
And it says that the build path is incomplete